# How to find duplicate text/records in webpage/table using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Am using this code to find matching text, i want to find duplicate records

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
String bodyText = body.getText();

// count occurrences of the string
int count = 0;

// search for the String within the text
while (bodyText.contains("VIM LIQUID MARATHI")){

// when match is found, increment the count
count++;

// continue searching from where you left off
bodyText = bodyText.substring(bodyText.indexOf("VIM LIQUID MARATHI") + "VIM LIQUID MARATHI".length());
```

}

Comment: This is clear for me, but my qyuestoin is ,now iam directing to a web page, it contains n number of text, how can i find that webpage contains duplicate texts,,,,say in that page the text (Zebra )displayed/listed 2 times, it should find zebra as duplicate, like that i want the script for the above scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can use findElements with xpath to find all elements that match the locator. This will return a list which you can get the size of, and this will automatically be your duplicate count.

```
String textToFindDuplicatesOf = "VIM LIQUID MARATHI";
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text() = '" + textToFindDuplicatesOf + "']"))
int count = elements.size();
```

Now `if(count > 1)` means you have duplicate records.

Now if you want to re-use this for other texts just add it to a method:

```
public boolean isDuplicateFound(String textToFindDuplicatesOf) {

    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text() = '" + textToFindDuplicatesOf + "']"))
    return elements.size() > 2;
}
```

Try something like this to find ALL duplicates on a page. I didn't test this there might be some mistakes:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()]"));
Map<String, Integer> textCounts = new HashMap<>();

for (WebElement element : elements) {

    String text = element.getText();
        if (textCounts.containsKey(text)) {

            textCounts.put(text, textCounts.get(text) + 1);
        } else {

        textCounts.put(text, 1);
    }
}
```

To print this to console...:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : textCounts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: This is clear for me, but my qyuestoin is ,now iam directing to a web page, it contains n number of text, how can i find that webpage contains duplicate texts,,,,say in that page the text (Zebra )displayed/listed 2 times, it should find zebra as duplicate, like that i want the script for the above scenario

Comment: Just change the text in the xpath to Zebra? Let me change my example to make it easier to see.

Comment: say in that webpage , it has thousands of texts, am i need to find only the duplicate records, i cannot search individually right?

Comment: Perhaps if you told me what the errors are I could help you with it. But really, I've shown you so much already, you can't use what I gave you to get to a working solution?

Comment: My script was passed, i want to display the duplicate records in my console , how to print that

Comment: Seriously?? You have the HashMap textCount which contains the duplicate entries AND the amount of times it is duplicate. Just print the HashMap contents to console???

Answer (score 0):

This will give you every text of an `WebElement` which contained your search text:

```
String searchString = "VIM LIQUID MARATHI";
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text() = '" + searchString + "']"));

for(WebElement we:elements){
   System.out.println(we.getText());
}
```

Comment: This is clear for me, but my qyuestoin is ,now iam directing to a web page, it contains n number of text, how can i find that webpage contains duplicate texts,,,,say in that page the text (Zebra )displayed/listed 2 times, it should find zebra as duplicate, like that i want the script for the above scenario

Comment: So far you only ask to find the duplicates :-). What do you want do afterwards ? Is there an link connected to the text, an image? Just tell what you want to do after finding the text

Comment: if webpage has thousands of texts, am i need to find only the duplicate records, i cannot search individually right? ..... i just want to print the duplicate records thats all

Comment: You want to get the text/sentence/WebElement which contains the keyword you were searching for (for every occurence)?

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: How to search for every occurence

Comment: My answer will give you every WebElement which contains your searched text